# How to make blocking code into non-blocking in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Im building a vue application where it did genetic algorithm to finding shortest route. Im using google maps api for fetching distance matrix, and also using vue2-google-maps package for simplicity. My code store the data fetched by api to array, let say i have 7 locations, when path A to B distance was fetched from google i store it in an array. So i doesnt need to make API request again if in the next route have path A to B. Example:

```
#Population 1
Route 1 : 1-2-3-4-5-6-7 = 10km //total distance of route 1
Route 2 : 7-2-1-3-5-4-6 = 20km
Route 3 : 1-2-6-3-4-7-6 = 15km
...
```

and this is how i store path that have been called from google api.

```
savedNodePath={1:
                 {2:1.2km}
                 {4:2km}
                   ...
                          }
```

where im expecting to create matrix array like this :

| From/To | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 0 | 3km | 1.2km | 4km | 2km |
| **2** | 5.2km | 0 | 6km | 2km | 11km |
| **3** | 8km | 5km | 0 | 4km | 2km |

That being said, if i had 7 locations i only need to fetch data from google maps about 49 times. And here goes the problem. When it still calling API from google, my page was still reactive, its updating the path distance reactively from path 1 to another. But when its no longer calling api since all the possible path are stored in my array. The proccess starting "freeze" and after some times all route distance was filled instantly.

This is how i calculate the distance from 1 point to another :

```
caclDistance: async function (a, b) {
  
    //if path from A isnt called yet.
    if (this.savedNodePath[a] === undefined) {
      let dist = await this.getDistanceApi(a, b).then((res) => {
        return res.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;
      });

      this.savedNodePath[a] = { [b]: dist};
      this.$set(this.savedMiniRoute, a, this.savedNodePath[b]);
      return this.savedNodePath[a][b];
    }
    //if path A to B are already called
    else if (this.savedNodePath[a][b]) {
      //I think this is the problem
      return this.savedNodePath[a][b];
    }
    //if path from A exist, but to B hasnt called yet
    else if (this.savedNodePath[a]) {
      let dist = await this.getDistanceApi(a, b).then((res) => {
        return res.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;
      });

      this.savedMiniRoute[a][b] = dist;
      this.$set(this.savedMiniRoute[a], b, dist);
    }
},
```

And this how i calculate the total path distance for route :

```
calcRoute: async function () {
  for (const i in this.route) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let j = 1; j < this.route[i].length; s++) {
      let a = this.route[i][j - 1];
      let b = this.route[i][j];
      let dist = await this.calcDistance(a, b).then((r) => {
        return r;
      });
      sum += dist;
    }
    if (sum < this.bestDist) {
      this.bestDist = sum;
      this.$set(this.bestPop, 1, this.population[i]);
    }
    this.$set(this.distance, i, sum);
  }
},
```

I've been trying to wrap the code i think was causing the problem in a promise, use nextTick, use setTimeout, none of them working. It still freezing when its no longer fetching google apis. Any idea how to work this out? Also if there is any way to make loading animation for this?

PS: im still beginner at javascript, im sorry for bad english and my bad code :)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see much value in calling matrix api n times, you could just add 7 coordinates to origins and 7 coordinates to destinations and you get 49 routes, if n=7

Comment: Not your issue but -> `then((r) => { return r; })` does nothing.

Comment: Oh thanks mate, i think if i put 7 origins and destinations it will return only 7 result. That could help me reduce the api request to google maps. @Keith jeez i forget why i did that lol, anyway thanks